# How to redirect facebook sharer after sharing or cancel?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sharer

I am fetching the posts of my app page using FB graph api and displaying them in ios app webview. I have a share button and it uses facebook sharer.php to share a post.

Now, my problem is that after sharing or cancel, the user is sent to facebook page and not to my web page.
I tried FB dialog feed which is supposed to solve this issue, but, FB dialog feed does not allow sharing of pictures hosted in FBCDN server .

```
 <?php
   $shareurl="http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=".$appid."&link=".urlencode($link)."&picture=".urlencode($pictureUrl)."&name=".urlencode($name)."&caption=".urlencode($caption)."&description=".urlencode($description)."&message=".urlencode($message)."&redirect_uri=".$redirectUri; 
 ?>
   <a href="<?php echo $shareurl; ?>" title="Share this post on Facebook" target="_blank">Share</a>
```

Automatically, all my app page photos are uploaded to FBCDN(http://photos-b.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/444_420079768083032_1721580062_s.jpg) So, I cannot use FB dialog feed.

I checked many similar questions in Stackoverflow which suggested dialog feed.
Is there a way to redirect sharer.php?

Comment: can you show some code??

Comment: Hi.. I have added the dialog feed code.. I use php.